# pass array by reference to named function in eventListener

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have the following line:

```
let array=[1,2,3]
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', submit);
```

I need to have the submit function modify array.  How do I pass the array into the listener?

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', () => submit(array))`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the array to the function by using another function:

```
let array = [1,2,3];
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', () => submit(array));
```

Comment: This will work, but the containing function is superfluous. It depends on the array being defined in the containing scope.  The inner function could just as easily refer to the array, which is necessarily in the contained scope of the containing function.